# Unable to mount and boot windows 7

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, mount, ntfs

I have Windows 7 and Linux Mint 16, and get this error when attempting to mount my Windows partition:

```
Error mounting /dev/sda2 at /media/bugsy/Windows: Command-line mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=0077,fmask=0177" "/dev/sda2" "/media/bugsy/Windows"' exited with non-zero exit status 14: Windows is hibernated, refused to mount.
Failed to mount **'/dev/sda2'**: Operation not permitted
The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown
Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume
read-only with the 'ro' mount option.
```

As for booting into Windows 7, booting doesn't even go my computer just get stuck right after I choose windows in the partition selection.

Since I can't even boot into windows, I can't fix the problem by making changes to the Windows partition from the Windows system itself.

Can anyone please tell me how to fix this problem so I will be able to boot into Windows again?

Comment: This is not about Ubuntu, or it's supported derivatives, and consequently it will be closed. This site is for Ubuntu only, not Linux mint. Try asking on [unix.se]

Comment: Could a mod move it?

Comment: @Tim If mods both here and on Unix.SE think it's suitable for migration, this is one option, yes. (Mods can be contacted with migration requests in chat or by flagging.) Questions are essentially only mod-migrated after closure. I'll vote to close with that in mind. (If it's not migrated and turns out to be helping Ubuntu users we could reopen it. I do agree that, strictly speaking, it is off-topic for our site.)

Comment: I think that might be a better option, as it won't help many others here. It would be better for the community on [unix.se]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to mount windows partiton,you may use following command. It will delete the hibernation file

`sudo mount -t ntfs-3g -o remove_hiberfile /dev/sda2 /media/Windows`

To boot into your windows, you need to repair your windows partition using windows cd, but it will delete the grub.

So first repair your windows partition and then re-install grub.